# Can the cluster_status callback submit new jobs?

Tags: python, dispy

I'm developing a dispy script operating on a large number of objects (duh).

There are multiple operations to be performed for each object -- only one of them must happen first, the rest use the first job's results and can be done in any order.

```
cluster = dispy.JobCluster(
    getShift,
    setup = functools.partial(doLoads, from, to),
    cluster_status = processed,
    nodes = Nodes
)
```

The straightforward way, I suppose, is to do two loops of `cluster.submit()` -- first loop for the first job for each object, and the second loop -- for all others.

However, I'd like to begin submitting the subsequent jobs as soon as the primary one is finished for each object -- without waiting for it to be done for all the other objects.

What's the right way to do that? In particular, can my `processed` callback function submit additional jobs to the same cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, callback can submit new job(s). See, for example, [job_scheduler.py](http://dispy.sourceforge.net/examples.html#example-bounded-jobs), which submits jobs in `callback` (although `cluster_status` can also be used for this purpose). From above description, it seems you can use `callback` instead of `cluster_status`.

Comment: Ha! I didn't even realize, "cluster_status" and "callback" are different things :)

Comment: Ehh, no, it is not working reliably. By the time the callback returns, the cluster-object may not even be valid any more -- because `cluster.wait()` in the main thread may have already returned... Should I file a bug report?